# GitKraken displaying old commit on top of the tree

Tags: git, merge, bitbucket, commit, gitkraken

I'm not sure if this was the best description of the issue I'm facing. What's happening here is totally weird.

I'm working in a project in which I use bitBucket integrated with gitKraken.
Here is the workflow:
1 - I commit changes to my own branch
2 - I update the main branch, merge it to my branch, resolve conflicts manually (if necessary)
3 - Merge my branch to the main branch

And so it goes that way, and after every new merge the tree in GitKraken changes, displaying always the last changes.

There is this one single commit that is messing up with my GitKraken Tree. I followed my workflow, and after a few other commits I realized that this particular old commit was still on the top of the tree. It seems like it is in another branch that is always on the top. It gives me the option to reset or revert the commit, but nothing really changes. I tried to create a branch in this commit and then erase it. Nothing changes.

I noticed there is an option in the bitBucket console called "stop watching". After clicking on it and realoding the page, it gos back to "stop watching.

Any idea how I could erase it?

[image]

Comment: Maybe compare this graphic representation with the textual output of `git branch` from the terminal?

Comment: @RomainValeri I kind of tried that by taking a look at the bitbucket panel. Everything seems to be okay there, but still I can't get rid of this commit on the top of the  graphic

Answer (score 2):

I need to apologize. It was my fault, I had changed the date in my computer to test something in my project. I had set a date in the future.
I ended up forgetting to return to the actual date and commited my code.
The commit was on the top because its date was in the future

Comment: Oh! I remember having searched for a while on this one! Thanks for the feedback :-)